# How to retrieve state from a component

Tags: reactjs, promise

I have a Modal dialog component that takes another component as content and returns a promise for handling the result (Idea is from [here](https://reactkungfu.com/2015/08/beautiful-confirm-window-with-react/)). How can I extract the 'time' state from the content in order to add it to the promise chain?

```
 import React from 'react'
    import Modal from './Modal'

    class Late extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {

            super(props);

            this.state = {
                time: '18:48'
            };
          }

        render() {

          return (
            <div className='modal-body'>
                {this.time}
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

    export default function(message, options) {

        var form = <Late description={options.description} />;

        return Modal(form, message, options).then(() => ??);
    }

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import '../css/modal.css'
import Promise from 'bluebird'
import _ from 'lodash'

Promise.config({ cancellation: true });

class Modal extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.resolve = null;
      }

    abort = () => this.promise.cancel();
    confirm = () => this.resolve();

    componentDidMount() {

        this.promise = new Promise(resolve => this.resolve = resolve);

        return ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.confirm).focus();
    }

    backdrop = () => <div className='modal-backdrop in' />;

    modal() {

      var style = {display: 'block'};

      return (
        <div
          className='modal in'
          tabIndex='-1'
          role='dialog'
          aria-hidden='false'
          ref='modal'
          style={style}
        >
            <div className='modal-dialog'>
                <div className='modal-content'>
                    <div className='modal-header'>
                        <h4 className='modal-title'>
                            {this.props.message}
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    {this.props.children}
                    <div className='modal-footer'>
                        <div className='text-right'>
                            <button type='button' className='btn btn-default' onClick={this.abort} >
                                {this.props.abortLabel}
                            </button>
                            {' '}
                            <button type='button' className='btn btn-primary' ref='confirm' onClick={this.confirm} >
                                {this.props.confirmLabel}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.backdrop()}
          {this.modal()}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  export default function(content, message, options) {

    var cleanup, component, props, wrapper;

    if (options == null) {

      options = {};
    }

    props = _.assign({

      message: message
    }, options);

    wrapper = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));

    component = ReactDOM.render(<Modal {...props}>{content}</Modal>, wrapper);

    cleanup = function() {

      ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(wrapper);

      return setTimeout(function() {

        return wrapper.remove();
      });
    };

    return component.promise.finally(cleanup);
  };
```

Comment: What is your Modal component code ?

Comment: @Treycos Added the code.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you correctly,  you wish to make some action once the Modal is done(pressed OK i.e). If so ,than you could wrap the Modal with a component and pass a function as a prop to the Modal so that once the Modal component is handling the wished action it can omit the function from prop.
[take a look how to pass a function as a prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-pass-an-event-handler-like-onclick-to-a-component), and [Lift up the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up)

Comment: Yes, although that's not insync with this design whereby the call to the modal is a function call like Javascript's `Confirm`.

Comment: I think the content needs access to the promise. Then it could add the `then` call itself.